# How to avoid JSON convert error between com.google.gson.JsonObject and com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: spring-mvc, serialization, jackson, gson

I use Microsoft Graph SDK for java to get outlook event list as below:

```
IEventCollectionPage eventPage = graphClient.users(email).calendar().events().buildRequest(requestOptions).select("subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location").get();
List<com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Event> eventList = evevtPage.getCurrentPage();
```

com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Event has a `com.google.gson.JsonObject rawObject`, and when it converted by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue`, I got error as below:

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
    com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:192)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:654)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1387)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:889)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:269)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    jp.co.smfl.ng.managers.spi.DefaultMaintenanceManagerFilter.doFilter(DefaultMaintenanceManagerFilter.java:41)
    jp.co.smfl.ng.securities.TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.java:164)
    jp.co.smfl.ng.securities.FormAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(FormAuthenticationFilter.java:280)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What can I do to parse it without exception?